# Does in_array() use a binary search algorithm?

Tags: php, binary-search, bsearch

I have a largish array of string that I want to use as a look-up.

I am using `in_array()`, but I *suspect* its doing a simple loop through - does anyone know whether the `in_array()` algo uses a bsearch algo?

Comment: Not sure if in_array does. I came across this, thought you might find it handy. http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#93352

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`in_array()` is `O(n)`.
Also see [List of Big-O for PHP functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473989/list-of-big-o-for-php-functions)

Answer (score 5):

Since it doesn't require the array to be sorted, I don't see how it could do a binary search.

Comment: I know it doesn't but to be fair, the OP may have thought that PHP was maintaining a sort-order under-the-hood.

Answer (score 4):

`in_array()` uses a linear (O(n)) search rather than a binary (O(log n)) search.

If you want O(log n) or better I would suggest you either put the values you want to search as the keys in an array or you create an index structure that effectively does the same thing.