# What does O(logn) + O(n) mean?

Tags: code-complexity

I was just told by someone that my code should follow the complexity guideline of O(logn) + O(n).  When prompted for clarification, I was presented with, "the complexity of the code :)"  In any event, any clarification over and above the provided would be appreciated.

Comment: O(log n) + O(n) = O(n), so I guess that certain someone is referring to combination of specific algorithms or parts of a given algorithm (if there is such).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
O(logn) + O(n) = O(n)
```

"I was just told by someone that my code should follow the complexity guideline of O(logn) + O(n)" - without knowing what your code is supposed to do, no one can answer what its reasonable complexity should be.

See [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Comment: Nice!  The link led me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473989/list-of-big-o-for-php-functions which provides proper context.  I'm messing with array_key_exists, and in_array to solve a programming riddle.  I'm still not exactly sure s/he was trying to get at (i.e. is this complexity for the arrays, or for the application as a whole).  I also see in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o/487278#answer-487278 that 0(log n) speaks to a logarithmic complexity, which in the telephone example, seems relevant to arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Without context, this is rather difficult to answer. "O(logn) + O(n)" by itself makes little sense because the asymptotic complexity of any given algorithm would be dominated by the linear term, so writing "+ O(logn)" doesn't clarify anything.