# How to combine an array with another array

Tags: php, arrays

I've two arrays array1 and array2 and I want to add all elements of array2 to the end of array1. array1 contains many items.

The keys are numeric and I don't want this syntax:

```
array1 = array1 + array2
```

or

```
array1 = SomeArrayFun(array1,array2)
```

As it takes away CPU times ( as array is created twice )

What I want is:

```
array1 . SomeAddFun(array2); // This will not create any new arrays
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: `As it takes away CPU times ( as array is created twice )`.  This is minuscule, and you won't notice any difference at all.

Comment: It is for heavy traffic site with thousands of records in the array

Comment: Take a look at this post benchmarking array functions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2484455

Comment: Ok so it seems `array_splice` is a *tiny bit* faster than `array_merge`.  http://ideone.com/qyxS3

Comment: If every programmer can optimize better then we can save power and in turn lot of CO2 emission :)

Comment: @Rocket: Nice link, +1, and I can imagine that `array_splice` is not always faster. Optimization needs concrete metrics, not a general use-case.

Comment: @user774250: Please back up that broad statement with some facts. I doubt that this will save any CO2 emission factually, would be nice, but I think the truth is something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'd like to append data to an existing array you should se [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php).

With the proper arguments you'll be able to insert/append the contents of `$array2` into `$array1`, as in the below example.

```
$array1 = array (1,2,3);
$array2 = array (4,5,6);

array_splice ($array1, count ($array1), 0, $array2);

print_r ($array1);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
)
```

Comment: @user774250 don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: Well actually, even if you don't see it, but [`array_splice`](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/array.c#2067) is creating a third hashtable internally. I would consider this shifts things only a bit around and [`array_merge`](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/array.c#2397) is probably faster as it doesn't have such a complicate function logic. You actually need to test which of those two ones is faster in the concrete usage.

Comment: @hakre: Seems `array_splice` is *slightly* faster than `array_merge`.  http://ideone.com/qyxS3

Comment: @hakre thanks, this is quite a bit of insight but array_merge is worst because it completely destroys and recreates array1 and I don't think Zend engine can optimize it anyway due to intervening assignment operator

Comment: @Rocket Use bigger arrays in your testcase and you will notice that `array_splice` is a lot faster when working with a bigger set.

Comment: Note: if the array to append is significantly smaller than the destination array, it's even faster (in comparison).

Comment: @hakre array_splice is made for splicing and not for appending the content so it's internal algorithm is oriented towards splicing. Your point is justified. In that case I should go with array_merge. There is no better function.

Comment: If the arrays are small, go with array_merge. If they are larger, better use array_splice. Like refp commented, that's what I know as well. Additionally array_merge allows multiple parameters as well, can make a difference, too. Choose wisely.

Comment: @hakre I thought I'd play around, and I found an even faster method, I'll post it together with a testcase, stay tuned. And you want to see this, it's not the most straight forward way to do it, but it's fast as fcuk!

Answer (score 0):

You might use `ArrayObject` with the `append` function:

```
$arrayobj = new ArrayObject(array('first','second','third'));
$arrayobj->append('fourth');
```

Result:

```
object(ArrayObject)#1 (5) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "first"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "second"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "third"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "fourth"
}
```

Don't know for appending arrays though, as they seem to be appended as a "subarray" and not as part of the whole.

Docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.append.php

Comment: Or use [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) on "normal" Arrays.

Comment: Pushing an array will add whole array with an index and not merge it's elements

Comment: @user774250, I only noticed it afterwards, and that's why I added the text at the bottom of the answer. I left my answer as it's still a way to append content to an array and might be useful information to others.