# PHP Array - Turning Array values into Keys

Tags: php, arrays, key

What is the MOST EFFICIENT way to have an array of values and turn it into an array of keys?
I'd really like to avoid any foreach loop...

```
$in = array(
    'red',
    'green',
    'blue'
);
```

INTO

```
$out = array(
    'red' => NULL,
    'green' => NULL,
    'blue' => NULL
);
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use PHP's [`array_flip`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) function.

---

On second thought, if you want the values to be null, then you might want to use [`array_fill_keys`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php):

```
$out = array_fill_keys($in, null);
```