# Time Complexity of array_filter in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, time-complexity, array-filter

Assuming that the callback function(s) that I am using have a time complexity of O(1), what is the running time of the [array_filter function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) in PHP and is there somewhere I can find the implementation of the array_filter function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of array_filter is in here, C-f for array_filter:
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c

I found the answer (which states that array_filter is O(n), not entirely unobvious seeing it needs to iterate over every item in the list exactly once):
[List of Big-O for PHP functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473989/list-of-big-o-for-php-functions)

Answer (score 1):

The complexity should be `O(N)`.

It just loop it and use the callback to check the element.

You could find ***[the implementation here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/array.c#4169)***.