# Is there a faster way for searching item in json array

Tags: php, json

Let says that I stored dataID in json file with 1,000,000 records.

My zresults.json  =  {"dataID":["1","2","3", ... "1000000"]}z

I want to find ID "100000" in the array.

```
$file = file_get_contents('results.json');
$data = json_decode($file,true);
if(in_array('100000', $data['dataID']))
{
  echo "found";
} else {
  echo "not found"; 
}
```

It took about 0.6 sec. for the result.

Is there a faster way for searching in json array like this?

Please give me an example!

Thank you in  advance.

**Update:**

Although sql would much faster but considered 1,000,000 record in one table the more record the more space!  At least, static file reduced server load and less space.

It depends on how designed your system.  Use it the right place and the right time!

Comment: half sec for million records is slow?

Comment: The duration obviously depends on the content of the data structure. If it is unordered, then only a brute force search can be done. This takes time.

Comment: How did you benchmark the time? Did you only time the if statement or did you also time loading up the json from the file reader and parsing it? 0.6 is indeed slow for an array search by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure!

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM data WHERE id = ?");
$stm->execute(array(100000));
if ($stm->fetchColumn())
{ echo "found"; } else { echo "not found"; }
```

you will need to import your array into database first.

Comment: This certainly is _much_ slower, except when you reuse that database for multiple searches later on.

Comment: yup, this is what databases are for. And JSON is not.

Comment: Yes, but do you know if that is what the OP wants? You posted this as an answer to his question...

Comment: Note that although havin a relational schema potentially allows for faster SELECT queries, it might take much effort to create and maintain such schema if the tree has a lot of branches. The mongo DB alternative might not be so bad.

Comment: `*sigh*`. whatever JSON arrays of 10000 elements aren't intended for search. But for data interchange only. While for search we use databases. Sincerely, Your Common Sense.

Comment: My reason for using json file is to avoid mysql database server overloading.  I generated the data from mysql into json file so user can just read from the json file instead.

Comment: @webmastx this is a perfect example of getting a contrary result out of good (but groundless) intentions. IN fact you **have** got your server loaded.

Comment: Should also be noted that a db server should not overload if indexes are correctly setup..

Comment: I think you have to query with the proper search then create the json to pass it over your objects (which is the intention of json)

Comment: @webmastx - although you had the best intentions of not overloading your database, who says that your solution was a proper one? It apparently creates problems.

Comment: Thanks everyone for replying. Based on a shared web server, Which one is the correct way?  search directly from mysql or from a static json file? 

If database is the best approach I may change to.

Thank you once again.

Comment: @webmastx apparently database is a most robust solution. Databases intended for search. And they have many means in speeding search up.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Havin an API which will communicate just via JSON and havin a web2.0 environment: meaning many updates while concurrent reads. Have tested it. I got better results with mongo DB.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Seems that you can think and event :D LOL

Comment: @YourCommonSense `SELECT 1 FROM data WHERE id = ?` Is this a power query? I ask because of the `?`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the structure of the data in the `results.json` file you may be able to do a simple string search for example

```
$file = file_get_contents('results.json');

if(strpos($file, '"100000"') !== false)
{
    echo 'found';
}
else
{
    echo 'not found';
}
```

After benchmarking your method I got around 0.78 seconds (on my slow local system) however with this method I achieved around 0.03 seconds.

Like I say, it depends on your data structure but if it does permit you to use this method you'll see significant speed benefits.

Comment: I created a file containing a json array in the same structure as that in the question with one million records in. Exactly like this `{"dataID":["1","2","3", ... "1000000"]}`

Comment: This doesn't count :D What if `{"dataID":["1","2","3",..."999999"],"userID":["1","2","3",...."1000000"]}` Then your script will return true, but it's not, his searching in "dataID", so you will need one more to use the json as an array to say in which key you want to search, which will slowdown the further strpos

Comment: That's why I made it clear that this option was only an option in the case where the data in the file permitted it. You are right, in this case my suggestion wouldn't work. However using the data and structure in the question it does work.

Comment: Why the down vote? This is an option and it answers the question.

Comment: It's not me the downvoter, maybe someone will comment its arguements about it

Comment: @user761389 Yes, strpos does faster than in_array it took from 0.6 to 0.3. I think because the json_decode has never been used! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store the id as keys and then do:

```
if(isset($data['dataID']['100000'])){
 // do something
}
```

Because checking if a key exists is alot faster than looping through the array. You can check out this link for further information:

[List of Big-O for PHP functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473989/list-of-big-o-for-php-functions)

Comment: You confuse array keys and values.

Comment: I forgot to add "Why don't you store the id as keys and then do:" :)

Comment: And why should that be faster?

Comment: Searching for the key is only faster if the data structure is unordered! Otherwise it scales exactly the same, since the same algorithm is used. But you don't know if the OPs data structure is ordered or not.

Comment: You sure?

"isset/array_key_exists is much faster than in_array and array_search"



"Lookups:

isset( $array[$index] ) O(n) but really close to O(1) - it uses the same lookup as array_key_exists. Since it's language construct, will cache the lookup if the key is hardcoded, resulting in speed up in cases where the same key is used repeatedly.

in_array O(n) - this is because it does a linear search though the array until it finds the value."

Otherwise I learned something new then...

Comment: I don't see how array_key_exists should come close to O(1), since no assumptions about the structure of the key set can be made in php... But I have not checked the algorithm, true. Caching certainly would help, but only for subsequent searches.

Comment: Em, I was a bit fast with my last comment... Obviously searching in the key set will perform near O(log(n))...

Comment: A lookup took me approximately 6.19*10^-6 s, but I created a list with assoc keys of "id-X" like "id-100000" :).

I've always used this approach when searching through arrays in stuff.

Comment: What does this show? You can get the same result when searching in the values, as said: it depends! There is no 'right' solution to this question because the OPs situation is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

A document based database like [mongo DB](http://www.mongodb.org/) is what you should try instead of working with plain json files - if you are bound to the json format.

Note that mongoDB can keep the json object in memory where plain PHP solutions had to parse the file again and again.

I see three performance boosts:

- less disk IO
- less parsing
- index based searches

Comment: This depends on the use case. Your approach _might_ be a good one, but how can you tell what the OPs situation is?

Comment: The situation is, that he want's to perform an index based search in a json document. (he told that). Note that mongoDB can keep the json object in memory where plain PHP solutions had to parse the file again and again

Comment: Yep. But also that he _has_ that JSON structure. You want to ask him to convert it just for a single search?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's possible to try to predict the outcome, you can then use in_array to search the value in a much smaller json.

Otherwise you could try alternative search algorithms, those can be complicated.