# exceeds execution time limit on pair difference challenge

Tags: php, performance, algorithm

I recently had to do a code challenge where I was instructed that for a set of numbers, find the number of pairs whose difference was K. For example, given then numbers `1, 5, 3, 4, 2`, and the difference K (2) there are 3 pairs: (5,3) (4,2) (3,1). I tried this challenge in PHP. My code passed the test, but was inefficient i guess because some of the test timed out. Can anyone tell me how I could have improved it? I'm bashing my head because I can't figure out how I could make it more efficient.

Here's my code

```
<?php
    // Open STDIN for reading
    $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

    // Get the input
    while(!feof($stdin)) {
        $inputs[] = explode(' ', fgets($stdin));
    }
    fclose($handle);

    $k = $inputs[0][1];
    $values = array_map('intval', array_values($inputs[1]));

    // Sort in decending order
    rsort($values);

    // Given the difference, K, find a pair for $left within
    // $right whose difference is K
    function findPair($k, $left, $right){
        foreach($right as $n) {
            if($left - $n == $k)
                return $n;
            // If the difference is greater than $k, there is no pair
            if($left - $n > $k)
                return false;
        }

        return false;
    }

    $pairs = 0;

    while(count($values) > 1){ 
        $left = array_shift($values);
        $n = findPair($k, $left, $values);

        if($n !== false)
            $pairs++;
    }

    echo $pairs;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code have `O(n^2)` complexity - and so it will be inefficient on large data sets. It's `O(n^2)` since you're looping through all array with `foreach` inside your function and calling it in `while` in external loop.

But you can easily do the stuff with `O(n x log(N))`:

```
function binSearch($array, $value, $from=null, $till=null)
{
   $from = isset($from)?$from:0;
   $till = isset($till)?$till:count($array)-1;
   if($till<$from)
   {
      return null;
   }
   $middle = (int)($from + ($till - $from)/2);
   if($array[$middle]>$value)
   {
      return binSearch($array, $value, $from, $middle-1);
   }
   if($array[$middle]<$value)
   {
      return binSearch($array, $value, $middle+1, $till);
   }
   return $middle;
}

$data = [1, 5, 3, 4, 2];
$k    = 2;

sort($data); //O(n x log(n))
$count = 0;

foreach($data as $value) //O(n)
{
   $count += null===binSearch($data, $value+$k)?0:1;//O(log(N))
}
var_dump($count);
```

-so, you will use standard [`sort()`](https://www.php.net/sort) with `O(n log(n))` complexity and then use binary search `N` times. Binary search has `O(log(n)) complexity`, so loop complexity will be also `O(n log (n))`. Therefore, whole code complexity will be `O(n log(n)) + O(n log(n)) = O(n log(n))`.

*Note:* standard PHP's [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/in_array) has [`O(N)` complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2484455/2637490), so using it will produce `O(N^2)` complexity estimation for loop, and, therefore, `O(N^2)` code complexity.

*Note:* sorting via `sort()` will produce [quick sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). This algorithm has `O(n log(n))` **average** complexity, it's worst case is `O(N^2)` - so there may be cases of data sets, for which code above may be also inefficient. You may look into other [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm). For example, if your problem is time limit, you may try [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) - it will be extremely faster (but it will take additional space).

**Note**: If we're speaking about time complexity and space complexity does not matter, it's just simple hash-map that can be used. In PHP it's just array:

```
$array = [1, 5, 3, 4, 2];
$k = 2;

$count = 0;
$map   = [];

foreach ($array as $number) //O(n) time
{
   $map[$number] = $number;
}
foreach($map as $key=>$nevermind) //O(n) time
{
   //O(1) if there are no duplicates, very close to O(1) otherwise
   $count += array_key_exists($key+$k, $map); 
}

var_dump($count);
```

-that will result in `O(n)` time complexity and `O(2n)=O(n)` space complexity.