# SplDoublyLinkedList to array

Tags: php, arrays, linked-list, type-conversion

In PHP, how should I convert an `SplDoublyLinkedList` to an array? As far as I can see, there is no `toArray` method or suchlike.

Obviously I can implement this myself, but I expected that there would be an efficient provided method for this.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need to do this: [`SplDoublyLinkedList`](http://php.net/SplDoublyLinkedList) implements [`Iterator`](http://php.net/Iterator), [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/ArrayAccess) and [`Countable`](http://php.net/Countable), meaning you can treat it like an array in almost all of your code.

If you need to persist it, it's safe to use in `serialize`.  There should not be a need to actually transform it into an array unless you're calling a built-in function that operates *only* on real arrays.

If you *absolutely must* transform it into a real array, you can take advantage of `foreach` working with iterators:

```
$l = new SplDoublyLinkedList();
$l->push('a');
$l->push('b');
$l->push('c');
$l->unshift('d');
var_dump($l);
/*
class SplDoublyLinkedList#1 (2) {
  private $flags =>
  int(0)
  private $dllist =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    string(1) "d"
    [1] =>
    string(1) "a"
    [2] =>
    string(1) "b"
    [3] =>
    string(1) "c"
  }
}
*/

$c = array();
foreach($l as $k => $v) { $c[$k] = $v; }
var_dump($c);
/*
array(4) {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "d"
  [1] =>
  string(1) "a"
  [2] =>
  string(1) "b"
  [3] =>
  string(1) "c"
}
*/
```

You *may* need to [rewind](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spldoublylinkedlist.rewind.php) the list before this.

Comment: Presumably `SplDoublyLinkedList` gives me O(n) array access?

Comment: I'm not sure actually, but [normal array lookups seem to be O(log n)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2484455/168868), if it actually matters to you.  Note the graph.  For most realistic array sizes, you aren't going to need to worry about performance.  Don't engage in premature optimization, break out xdebug and profile the code to *prove* that it's array access that's slowing your code down.