# What algorithm does array_sum use in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, php-internals

what algorithm does array sum uses to make it much faster than some looping through?

Is it prefix sum / suffix sum or something else?

Comment: I must be a linear algorithm too, but intrinsic PHP functions (i.e. all functions available in PHP directly) are executed faster

Comment: Basically the same algorithm that you'd implement if you wrote  loop to do it, but it's executing as straight compiled C code, not PHP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Algorithm is plain: just iterate through array and produce summation of elements. That's it. In terms of **algorithm** there's nothing more that could be said about it. Obviously, you'll have complexity as `O(n)` for it.

However, PHP `array_sum()` is a compiled C code, thus, is will be faster than user-land function. Also, if you're interested in how it works internally, you may check [`array_sum()` implementation](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/standard/array.c#4061):

```
for (zend_hash_internal_pointer_reset_ex(Z_ARRVAL_P(input), &pos);
    zend_hash_get_current_data_ex(Z_ARRVAL_P(input), (void **)&entry, &pos) == SUCCESS;
    zend_hash_move_forward_ex(Z_ARRVAL_P(input), &pos)
) {
    if (Z_TYPE_PP(entry) == IS_ARRAY || Z_TYPE_PP(entry) == IS_OBJECT) {
        continue;
    }
    entry_n = **entry;
    zval_copy_ctor(&entry_n);
    convert_scalar_to_number(&entry_n TSRMLS_CC);
    fast_add_function(return_value, return_value, &entry_n TSRMLS_CC);
}
```

(I've left only loop part itself). There's also `fast_add_function()` asm optimization, you can check out it's implementation [here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/Zend/zend_operators.h#592).

Comment: You win, master ninja.

Answer (score 1):

It uses the same algorithm as if you were to write a loop in PHP (that is, the O(n) linear solution), except in most cases since it's native code (written in i.e. C) and not interpreted, it runs directly on the CPU instead of via a virtual machine (which is between 10 and 100 times slower).

Answer (score 0):

It uses `Big-O O(n)` optimization. You might want to look at this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473989/list-of-big-o-for-php-functions) here. Also you can check most of this yourself by using software like [Eureqa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureqa)

Comment: "big O" is no way an "algorithm" which OP is asking

Comment: @raidenace : Thanks a ton, very valuable information.