# Using values as keys in arrays to reduce complexity when searching for items

Tags: php, arrays

Here is sometime I do a lot in PHP.  Searching for a needle in a haystack.

```
$names = [
    'Mike',
    'John',
    'Dave',
    'Tony'
];

$gotDave = in_array('Dave', $names);
```

The runtime of in_array is O(n) where n is the number of elements.

I often setup my lookup data structure to look like this.

```
$names = [
    'Mike' => true,
    'John' => true,
    'Dave' => true,
    'Tony' => true
];

$gotDave = isset($names['Dave']);
```

The runtime is O(1) because in php the associative array is a hashmap.

Some questions:

- should I do this?  is this good practice?
- is there a better value for the right hand ride

Comment: Personally I couldn't fault this..

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what do you mean by "*The runtime of in_array is `O(n)`*"? What does `O` stand for?

Comment: @D4V1D n = number of elements within the array

Comment: @D4V1D It called big oh notation.  You can google it for more info.

Comment: If you consider the complexity then **O(1)** is better then **O(n)**.

Comment: 1) It's fine. 2) It's fine. 3) Consider `array_fill_keys` for more concise syntax.

Comment: Note that this is not really one-to-one since you couldn't make the second array from `['Mike', 'Mike']`

Comment: @Explosion I'd assume the values are unique to begin with...

Comment: [_Obvious Big-O: array_fill_keys()_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473989/list-of-big-o-for-php-functions) @deceze

Comment: @Uchiha Meaning what? Yes, it's a little slower than writing a literal, but I'd assume the array initialisation only happens very rarely compared to the key lookup.

Comment: @deceze it's probably a safe assumption, but I'm pointing it out in case it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a great solution. In fact, that is how Sets are implemented in the core libraries of most programming languages - Off the top of my head, Python, Ruby, and Java do them this way. The Go language doesn't provide a Set, and just tells you to do what you've done.

I can't think of any reason to use any value other than true ```true``. It just makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `array_key_exists()` to check for the key of the array, unlike `in_array` which checks for values

you will have to use `array_key_exists()` instead of `isset()` in your case